# Could you rewrite the statements less formally?

Tags: math

I'm not sure this is an appropriate question here...

1. |a+b| <= |a|+|b|
2. |a-b| >= ||a|-|b||

It's dumb question but how do you read this?

my guess as below.

1. absolute value of sum a and b is less than sum of absolute value
   a and absolute value b.
2. absolute value of difference a and b is greater than absolute value of difference absolute a and absolute b.

Is this right? Or can I write it more simply?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that this is put any more simply than yours but it includes how I would say it if I was reading the problem aloud. Could add "The" to the beginning of both if they are to be a statement or "Is the" to make it a question.

1. Absolute value of a plus b is less than or equal to the absolute
   value of a plus the absolute value of b.
2. Absolute value of a minus b is greater than or equal to the absolute value of the absolute value of a minus the absolute value of b.